# Probability with Catalan number with more open parenthesis

Tags: probability, combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Two candidates A and B raced each other in an election campaign. Candidate A
accumulated a votes and candidate B accumulated b votes. Assuming a > b what
is the probability that candidate A was leading all the way?

the answer is surprisingly  $ \frac {a-b}{a+b} $

I had tried a few things such try to count all the vectors with 2b parenthesis and rearrange the $a-b$ rest parenthesis.
tried to define a few recursive sequences. but nothing works.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: awesome thank you!!